# AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, datetime, python-dateutil

Im trying to convert a str to a date object using the python-dateutil library

```
from dateutil.parser import *

datetime_object = parse('Fri Feb 14 19:39:51 +0000 2020')
pprint("DATETIME", datetime_object )
```

However i get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: why are you using pprint and not your regular print function?

Comment: Ah forgot im using pprint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pprint` documentation states that the arguments must have the `write` method implemented.  `datetime` does not.  I expect that your easiest path to a solution is to use any of the available `str` conversions in `datetime`, such as the various `format` specifications.

Comment: ahh forgot im using pprint